# Sending data from NSObject to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

I have been working on this problem for close to 4 days now.

I am at the point where I think its not so much a problem with my code, but the structure of my application that is causing the issue.

I am trying to implement protocols and delegates to get an array from one NSObject(class) to a ViewController.

my code is pretty much line by line copied from this [tutorial](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/delegates/how-to-create-a-delegate) the only differences are in the face I have ARC turned on so have had to replace (nonatomic, retain) to (strong) and have not used dealloc :)

so with that being said its still not passing the data back to the viewcontroller. (highly annoying) I have tried dozens of different combinations of solutions that I have had help with and nothing has worked. This has lead me to believe that maybe there is an error in the structure of my application or the way things have been initialized etc, which I will attempt to explain now.

When my viewcontroller with tableview loads the viewdidload method called the delegate of my  parser class, then once the first cell of the tableview has loaded it called my connection class and tells it to download some data from the server.
Inside my connection class I use NSURLConnection delegates from the apple library, in the delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading the data that has been downloaded is passed over to my parser class (however this is where i think its going wrong because i declare the object again.. which i think is where things are going amiss)

this is how I call my parser class from my connection class.

```
parserClass *myparser = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
[myparser  ReciveResponse:receivedData];
```

then once the data is in my parser class it gets parsed and then I try to pass the data across to my viewcontroller.. but its never accessing that delegate method that I set up.

Hopefully this is where the problem is because I just dont know where else I am going wrong.
what do you think?

UPDATE: heres my code -

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "EngineResponses.h" //delegates & protocols

interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <PassParsedData> {

//delegates to parser class
    EngineResponses *engineResponses;
//..
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "EngineResponses.h"

//this is where I set up the delegate/protocol for the parser class
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//..
engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
[engineResponses setMydelegate:self];
//..
}

//this is where i set up and call the connection class
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//..
if(indexPath.section == 0){        
    //..
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
     EngineRequests *engineRequests = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
                [engineRequests initalizePacketVariables:0 startCode:@"myReg" activationCode:@"myAct" methodName:@"GetStuff"];
                //..
}

#pragma - Reciver methods

- (void)sendArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    ICMfgFilterArray = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

**EngineRequests.m**

```
//connection delegates etc..
//then I pass the data from the connection delegates over to the parser class
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{   
    EngineResponses *engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
    [engineResponses  ReciveResponse:receivedData];
}
```

**EngineResponses.h**

```
@protocol PassParsedData
- (void)sendArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end

//..
id <PassParsedData> mydelegate;
//..
@property (strong) id  <PassParsedData> mydelegate;
```

**EngineResponses.m**

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
//..
    [[self mydelegate]sendArray:filteredArray];    
}
```

1

Comment: A redacted version of your code will be easier to diagnose than a prose description.

Comment: um, are you doing something like `[myParser setDelegate:myViewController];`? Also, really need to see your code to propose a better solution.

Comment: okay, I have updated with my code.. sorry it took so long, just made sure I have everything in perfectly.. So IMO i think the error is that i am allocating the parser object in two places... but im not sure if this is correct or how to solve it.

Comment: Well, do your "file names" match your class names? Or is ParserClass your EngineResponses? It seems to be. If so then you allocate it twice for no reason. In connectionDidFinish you creat a new one. This now one has its mydelegate initially set to nil (I guess). So when you send the sendArray message ot mydelegate, which is nil, then you send a message to a nil object. This will cause neither compiler nor runtime error but it will certainly not execute the method sendArray. Make sure that your connection class gets a reference to the parser class object.

Comment: yes, engineRequest is the connectionclass, and engineResponse is the parser class.. these are correct.. but i just labled the sections of code for clarity.

Comment: Ahhh so it is as I suspected.. however how do I "Make sure that your connection class gets a reference to the parser class object"

Comment: See the answer that I just wrote. Frankly, with messing up the file names you did not really add much clarity. At least you could have added the interface and implementation statements just to let us know hat corresponds to what. :)

Comment: sorry, I thought it would add better clarity as to what their purposes were.. I have now changed the titles to match up to the actual method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright. I will re-do it based on your updated code. To make it easy I copy your code and do the amendments.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "EngineResponses.h" //delegates & protocols

interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <PassParsedData> {

//delegates to parser class
    EngineResponses *engineResponses;

    EngineRequests *engineRequests;  
//..
```

Explanation:
You are using ARC. If you define the pointer locally, as you did before, and to not 
retain it - which you can't because of ARC - then it will be released directly after its 
creation. You will have to keep at least one reference to the object. 
Bare in mind that ARC means Automatic Reference Counting. As soon as there is no 
reference to an object it will be released. 
This proposal with the engineRequests object defined here only works while you 
submit only one request at a time. If you have several requests, i.e. for more than one cell or 
whatver, then you may go for a mutable array or mutable dictionary where you keep the requests while you use them.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "EngineResponses.h"

//this is where I set up the delegate/protocol for the parser class
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//..
engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
[engineResponses setMydelegate:self];

engineRequests = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];  // Use instance variable instead of local variable
[engineRequests setEnineResponses:engineResponses];

//..
}

//this is where i set up and call the connection class
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//..
if(indexPath.section == 0){        
    //..
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
     [engineRequests initalizePacketVariables:0 startCode:@"myReg" activationCode:@"myAct" methodName:@"GetStuff"];
                //..
}

#pragma - Reciver methods

- (void)sendArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    ICMfgFilterArray = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Explanation: The engineRequets is now an instance varaible and should not be re-defined locally. 
You could define a variable of the same name locally which would hide the instance variable. I think
in that case you get a compiler warning but that will work and will most probably confuse you. 
Again, if you use more than one request at a time then this solution will not work!

**EngineRequests.h**

```
EngineResponses *engineResponses;
```

**EngineRequests.m**

```
@synthesize engineResponses;

//connection delegates etc..
//then I pass the data from the connection delegates over to the parser class
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{   
    //EngineResponses *engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init]; //This Object has already been created! 
    [engineResponses  ReciveResponse:receivedData];
}
```

Explanation: Here, too, the reference to EngineResponses is now an instance variable, not a locally defined one. The object will not be newly created but it references to that very object that was created in the view controller. That is the one EngineResponses that 'knows' its view controller object and can therefore pass back the parsed data.

**EngineResponses.h**

```
@protocol PassParsedData
- (void)sendArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end

//..
id <PassParsedData> mydelegate;
//..
@property (strong) id  <PassParsedData> mydelegate;
```

**EngineResponses.m**

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
//..
    [[self mydelegate]sendArray:filteredArray];    
}
```

... give it a try :)

Comment: unfortunately.. I don't quite understand what I need to do here, based off your answer.

Comment: when I call [engineRequests setMydelegate:self]; from cellForRowAtIndexPath i get this error ** Reciver type 'EngineRequests' for instace message dose not declare a method with seclector 'setMyDelegate'**

Comment: hi, where you say to **[engineRequests setMydelegate:self];** did you mean to say **[engineResponses setMydelegate:self];** or something else because what you have said to do is not working out atm.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to bed at some time. It was well after midnight anyway. :)

Comment: awesome :) I'll give it a crack now :)

Comment: OMG... it worked! LOL thank you so much!! so the issue i was having was not initalizing things correctl, and the not calling them right.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for nil objects.  Sending a message to a nil object will do nothing and your app will continue.  I bet this is the problem since you are locally allocing all over the place.  Why dont you make the receivedata method a static method instead since it looks like you dont need these classes for more than a few moments for some calculations and parsing.  Then nil objects wont be a factor.

Comment: Having connectionDidFinisLoading etc. in the viewController works fine if there is only one request at a time "on the air". In the event that individual requests are sent out for a number of table cells then C.Johns' approach is much saver.